# How to put the multiple duplicate query results of different tables in a readable format

Tags: sql-server

I have some 72 sql queries   to find out the duplicates in each of the tables.Each query is for a different table and different columns and the number of columns also differ to attain a unique combination.Is there a way I can execute them and put the result in a tabular format? I can execute individual query and I get the result though, But then I have to collect the results individually. Any sql code to put them all in a readable format?

```
For Eg: 1 Query is on 1 column-- 0 rows returned
2 Query is on 2 columns -- 0 rows returned.
3 query is on 1 column-- 323 rows returned.
```

Comment: If the queries return sufficiently similar data you could use `union all` to link them into a single query. But without specifics in the question cannot be specific in an answer.

Comment: all the queries will return if there are duplicates are not the query is either one more columns to retrieve a unique combination.

Comment: All tables columns may not be identical.so you must reframe your question with more details like expected output

Comment: I just edited it.